# pod installation failed with react native 0.44

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I was working on a react native project with the local database. I used this https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage for local database access. It was working fine with RN 0.41.

But now when I upgrade my RN version to 0.44 I am getting following errors with pod install.

```
Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `Yoga (= 0.44.0.React)` required by `React/Core (0.44.0)`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Yoga (= 0.44.0.React)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

This is my podfile:

```
target 'ProjectName' do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native' <br>
  pod 'react-native-sqlite-storage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage'
end
```

I have tried lots of things but not able to solve this error. I created a new react project but and it was not working in that too

Comment: Facing the same problem. Any luck with the solution?

Comment: Yes. It was working for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
```

Comment: You might want to provide a little more details to your answer, like introducing what's missing, and posting the full, corrected podfile so the OP (and anyone else) can know what to change more easily if they encounter the error

Comment: Thanks for this! The reason is works is because Yoga is required ... so adding this line meets the required dependency.